# Google apps script - using for loop to pull data from range based on condition

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I'm having an issue pulling the correct values out of a for loop in Google Sheets.
Here's my code:
**Note: this is a snippet from a larger function**

```
function sendEmails() {
var trackOriginSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var getMirSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Miranda");

//Set a new object to hold conditional data
var holdingData = new Object();

//Create function to get values from origin sheet
var returnedValues = function (trackOriginSheet) {

//Load dynamic variables into an object via returnedValues()
    if (trackOriginSheet === getMirSheet) {

        var startMirRow = 2; // First row of data to process
        var numRowsMir = 506; // Number of rows to process

        // Fetch the range of cells A2:Z506
        var dataRangeMir = getMirSheet.getRange(startMirRow, 1, numRowsMir, 26);

        // Fetch values for each cell in the Range.
        var dataMir = dataRangeMir.getValues();

        for (var k in dataMir) {
            var secondRowMir = dataMir[k];
            var intRefDescMir = secondRowMir[3];
            var intAdminActionsMir = secondRowMir[4];

            //Push returned data to holdingData Object
            holdingData.selectedData = secondRowMir;
            holdingData.refDesc = intRefDescMir;
            holdingData.adminActions = intAdminActionsMir;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's a copy of the sheet I'm working on](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tXArqAUlawOJoFLpeCIk2H13VkpClY5f0lo_MMdXwT4/edit?usp=sharing)

What I need to have happened here first, is track the origin sheet, then create an object to hold data returned from the returnedValues() function. Later, I'll call the properties of this object into a send email function.

The problem is that I need to be able to pull data from the selected sheet dynamically (the "Miranda" sheet in this case.) In other words, when a user selects the "Yes" option in column I of the Miranda sheet, the first thing this script needs to do is pull the values of the variables at the top of the for loop *within the same row that the user selected "Yes."* Then, I'm pushing that data to a custom object to be called later.

It's apparent to me, that I'm doing it wrong. There's, at least, something wrong with my loop. What have I done? :)

**EDIT:**
After reviewing the suggestion by VyTautas, here's my attempt at a working loop:

```
for (var k = 0; k < dataMir.length; k++) {
            var mirColI = dataMir[k][8];
            var mirRefDesc = dataMir[k][2];
            var mirAdminActions = dataMir[k][3];
            var mirDates = dataMir[k][4];
            if (mirColI === "Yes") {
              var activeRowMir = mirColI.getActiveSelection.getRowIndex();
              //Pull selected values from the active row when Yes is selected
              var mirRefDescRange = getMirSheet.getRange(activeRowMir, mirRefDesc);
              var mirRefDescValues = mirRefDescRange.getValues();
              var mirAdminActionsRange = getMirSheet.getRange(activeRowMir, mirAdminActions);
              var mirAdminActionsValues = mirAdminActionsRange.getValues();
              var mirDatesRange = getMirSheet.getRange(activeRowMir, mirDates);
              var mirDatesValues = mirAdminActionsRange.getValues();
              var mirHoldingArray = [mirRefDescValues, mirAdminActionsValues, mirDatesValues];
              //Push mirHoldingArray values to holdingData
              holdingData.refDesc = mirHoldingArray[0];
              holdingData.adminActions = mirHoldingArray[1];
              holdingData.dates = mirHoldingArray[2];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did all that whitespace go in the actual script editor? :D

You already correctly use `.getValues()` to pull the entire table into an array. What you need to do now is have a for loop go through `dataMir[k][8]` and simply fetch the data `if dataMir[k][8] === 'Yes'`. I also feel that it's not quite necessary to use `for (var k in dataMir)` as `for (var k = 0; k < dataMir.length; k++)` is a lot cleaner and you have  a for loop that guarantees control (though that's probably more a preference thing).

You can also reduce the number of variables you use by having

```
holdingData.selectedData = mirData[k]
holdingData.refDesc = mirData[k][2] //I assume you want the 3rd column for this variable, not the 4th
holdingData.adminActions = mirData[k][3] //same as above
```

remember, that the array starts with 0, so if you `mirData[k][0]` is column A, `mirData[k][1]` is column B and so on.

**EDIT:** what you wrote in your edits seems like doubling down on the code. You already have the data, but you are trying to pull it again and some variables you use should give you an error. I will cut the code from the if, although I don't really see why you need to both get the active sheet and sheet by name. If you know the name will be constant, then just always get the correct sheet by name (or index) thus eliminating the possibility of working with the wrong sheet.

```
   var titleMirRows = 1; // First row of data to process
   var numRowsMir = getMirSheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process

// Fetch the range of cells A2:Z506
   var dataRangeMir = getMirSheet.getRange(titleMirRows + 1, 1, numRowsMir - titleMirRows, 26); // might need adjusting but now it will only get as many rows as there is data, you can do the same for columns too

// Fetch values for each cell in the Range.
   var dataMir = dataRangeMir.getValues();

   for (var k = 0; k < dataMir.length; k++) {
     if (dataMir[k][7] === 'Yes') {    //I assume you meant column i
       holdingData.refDesc = dataMir[k] //this will store the entire row
       holdingData.adminActions = dataMir[k][3] //this stores column D
       holdingData.dates = dataMir[k][4] //stores column E
     }
   }
```

Double check if the columns I have added to those variables are what you want. As I understood the object stores the entire row array, the value in column called *Administrative Actions* and the value in column *Dates/Periods if Applicable*. If not please adjust accordingly, but as you can see, we minimize the work we do with the sheet itself by simply manipulating the entire data array. Always make as few calls to Google Services as possible.

Comment: Because mirData[k] is fetching every cell in row 8, as a row object within an array, and running a for loop within that to look for a string would pull the actual cell. NOW it makes sense :) thank you! I'll try this out this morning and report back

Comment: I think I understand how to implement what you're saying here (as far as the loop) Am I on track with the code in the edit above?

Comment: Edited with my end of the day realization :) I believe this will work, but feel free to correct me. Also, I'd like to cut the variables down a bit, but am out of time right now

Comment: @Jensen010 please see my edits on the answer. Looking at your `for` loop, if nothing else has changed, you are doing the same thing twice. You already have `dataMir` which should be all the data you want and the only other call you want to do with that sheet is if you change anything in it. I have also changed `numRowsMir` so that you only get the data you need

Comment: ooooook, this makes sense to me now. I don't know why I didn't think of just selecting a cell value by pushing the column to the object, since the row is already active. I knew it could be simpler, but didn't have time to work at it :) Thank you for all of your help! It may not feel like it, but you've helped me gain some confidence in my abilities (you've inspired me to rewrite and simplify a bunch of code I haven't posted:)

Comment: Oh! And what you were saying about the active sheet, I will be reusing this function for all 4 of the individual sheets in this document. I plan on using else if() statements or just one big switch :)

Comment: @Jensen010 what I meant is that depending on how it's run it would be different, but the current setup is doing an extra step of getting a sheet. So if `trackOriginSheet` is the active sheet and you want to check if it's `Miranda`, `Piper` or whatever other sheet, you can simply get the sheet, then `switch(trackOriginSheet.getName())` and `case 'Miranda':`, `case 'Piper':` and so on, which will save you extra calls to the spreadsheet service. No 2 sheet names can be the same and regardless of how you do this, changing a sheet name will require a change in code.

Comment: Also, on another note after another quick glance at the spreadsheet, apart from `Master` they are all the same. Try to use as much common code as possible. So if you always want those 3 variables, then they do not need to be under an `if` or `switch`. Instead always get that data based on `.getActiveSheet()` and if you want to change that data differently based on which sheet it is do that under `if` or `switch` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried to give myself a break all weekend, but had this exact thought while I was laying in bed last night :) I definitely need to go through and write common code with less calls for this whole thing, I think my focus has been on just getting it functional right now.

Comment: I put everything together today and cut a ton out that was redundant. Thank you for your suggestions and help! If anyone is interested, I made another post with my latest hurdle over here - stackoverflow.com/questions/41561887/ I really think this thing is just about together